# Meteor optional template

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

So I have started to learn Meteor and trying to get my head around how I should format the template correctly. This is how I set up my project:

- A/view.html - html file for template A
- A/script.js - import A/view.html. Potentially be the "controller" to work with the interaction
- B/view.html - html file for template B
- B/script.js - import A/view.html. Potentially be the "controller" to work with the interaction
- routes.js - route file, include all script.js for template A and B

So I have two questions:

- First, I want to make A as the base template, meaning it will have style and javascript tags as well as a "styles" and "scripts" **optional** blocks in case the child template wants to add extra files. **How can I do this?** I have tried normal ways:

  - Creating 2 blocks named *styles* and *scripts* in each child templates. This doesn't work since routes.js imports everything, meteor complains there are 2 templates having the same name
  - Using Template.dynamic. This work but I have to declare what template I want to render in the block of "styles" and "scripts", which is a bit untidy, in my opinion, when the project goes big.
- The second question, as I described what I am currently doing with my routes, **what is the best way to localize(?) the block to the current file?**. Would it be possible to have 2 blocks called "scripts" in 2 different child templates and meteor not complaining?

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "blocks", but I assume you want to have A be the template that everything else fits into, and then have other pages feed into it?

If so, it sounds like you would want to use dynamic templates, and have A be a layout.

Here is an example of a layout, which imports other templates from one of my projects (It actually imports two constant templates (loginNavbar and modalWindow) as well as dynamic ones depending on what I call to it. You could add as many styles and other things as you want to the layout itself):

```
<template name="loginLayout">
    <div class="loginNavbarTemplateDiv">
        {{> loginNavbar}}
    </div>
    <div class="loginContentTemplateDiv">
        {{> Template.dynamic template=content}}
    </div>

    {{> modalWindow}}
</template>
```

So then my routes.js looks like this (renders the outside loginLayout with the inner content of login or register):

```
FlowRouter.route('/login', {
    name: 'login',
    action: function() {
        BlazeLayout.render("loginLayout", { content: 'login' });
    }
});

FlowRouter.route('/register', {
    name: 'register',
    action: function() {
        BlazeLayout.render("loginLayout", { content: 'register' });
    }
});
```

Overall, I wouldn't have two templates named the same thing, and if you structure your files/app properly, it shouldn't be too untidy.

Please let me know if this helps and if you have any other questions, I'd be glad to help.

-

Here is a great tutorial on dynamic templates if you want more:

https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/using-dynamic-templates

And a guide on how to structure your Meteor app files (helps a ton and makes everything better):

https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html

Comment: @Tree Nguyen - Any progress or news?